# Sony Smartwatch Widget icon in wrong position

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am setting the icon for my apps widget as part of getSourceRegistrationConfiguration:

```
String iconSource1 = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.watchwidgeticon);
sourceValues.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ICON_URI_1, iconSource1);
```

While the icon does display, it is displayed slightly above and to the left of the position it should be in, and the standard circle icon is displayed where ICON_URI_1 should be.

Any ideas as to why this would be happening, and how to correct it?

[See what I mean here](http://download.wilsonsa.dyndns.org/watchicon.png)

The icon circled in red should be in the bottom right hand corner

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you upload your icon file somewhere? What do you mean by standard circle icon? Maybe a photo of the actual SmartWatch display would help, too. Also, is this for SmartWatch 1 or SmartWatch 2?

Comment: This is for SmartWatch 1. By standard circle icon I mean the new Event icon. Will see if I can find a web server to put the files on

Comment: So this is about the order of the icons being displayed, is it? Or is it about the icon being out of place for a few pixels? Just want to make sure I got it right.

Comment: Out of place by about the size of the icon itself. And then the "New Event" icon is being displayed when it shouldn't.

Comment: Edited my post to include link to a photo so you can see what i mean

Comment: OK, got it, makes things clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is actually the correct behavior when showing the standard notification widget. This widget not only shows the notification of your app, but of all apps.

What you really wanted to see is your own widget. You first have to enable it:

1. Start Smart Connect on your phone
2. Choose SmartWatch
3. Settings
4. Apps
5. Your app
6. Select to show as widget

Now on your SmartWatch scroll to the right and you will see your own widget with the icon in the right place.